# Spring DeferredResult setResult causing 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using the new spring 3.2 async servlet requests.
All works well except in this one scenario...

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<byte[]> test(InputStream is, HttpServletResponse response, WebRequest request) {
    if (someTest()) {
        deferredResult.setResult(DATA);
        return deferredResult;
    }

    deferredResult.onTimeout(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            deferredResult.setResult(DATA);
        }
    });

    // Use deferredResult in another thread when needed

    return deferredResult;
}
```

When `someTest()` is true spring/tomcat returns a 404. I am not sure how I should go about this or why this happens? I assume it might be because the Servlet Async Context has already been created. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Any info will be appreciated!

Comment: Pls see this [bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10410) created on Spring (that was resolved as Invalid) !
They faced the exact same issue you faced !
The only way is to set the deferredResult outside of the Controller service method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, see below...

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<byte[]> test(InputStream is, HttpServletResponse response, WebRequest request) {
    if (someTest()) {
        response.getOutputStream().write(DATA);
        return null;
    }

    deferredResult.onTimeout(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            deferredResult.setResult(DATA);
        }
    });

    // Use deferredResult in another thread when needed

    return deferredResult;
}
```

Trick is to return null and write the response manually to the ServletResponse.

Hope this comes in use to someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the statement `return deferredResult` from the if condition.

And also the setData should be done after the return statement. So you need to do that from a separate thread on some server side event.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Doesnt really help as some conditions should return the a result immediately and other should "park" for another thread to use.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a weird `404` lately with a legacy project that uses `DeferredResult` and it was a matter of adding `@ResponseBody`. A simple runnable example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }

    @Controller
    static class Rest {

        @Autowired
        private MyService myService;

        @GetMapping("/get")
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
        @ResponseBody // <-- with and without
        public DeferredResult<String> get() {
            return myService.go();
        }
    }

    @Service
    static class MyService {
        public DeferredResult<String> go() {

            DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();

            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
                System.out.println("starting work");
                LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(5));
                System.out.println("done with work");
                result.setResult("done");
            });

            return result;
        }
    }

}
```